# Undo "Report Spam" in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I have unintentionally "Report Spam"ed an email that I meant only to archive from a frequent legitimate contact. Are there spam rule controls somewhere in Gmail that I can reverse the effect of my error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can go into your Spam folder in Gmail, select the mail in question and click the "Not Spam" button. Gmail should be smart enough to remove the contact and characteristics of the mail from its internal spam definition.